# Eclipse: on new projects, which mode: debug or release?

Tags: project, eclipse, release

I'm asked to teach my students Eclipse.

The lectures are already done; I see that the teacher asks the students to **always** start a new project in "Release" mode.

[image: Eclipse Screenshots]

Is this a good idea? If "yes", or if "no", why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is normal or not but in general it is a matter of preference for the teacher.

I am not sure that not letting students debug their programs is any good for learning but I would ask him the reason why he limits this.

One thing that I can think of is to teach the ability to add another build configuration if problems arise.